# Jquery add class to element on click, remove that same class from previous item.

Tags: jquery, css

```
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">

img.active {
    border: 5px solid black;
}

$(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChilledMonkeyBrain/sLv8gvy9/

Easy points to anyone who has basic knowledge of JQ. I've done this before, but I can't remember how. Been at it for ages, so need to ask for help.

Very simply, clicking on an image gives it a border. When you click on the next image it should remove the border from the previous image as well as adding it to the current image. What is this called again?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would `removeClass` from all, and then `addClass` to current:

```
$('img').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Depending on the situation, something more context specific may be needed, such as:

```
$(this).siblings('img').removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
```

If there is a huge number of them and you want to avoid `removeClass` on all, you could limit the remove selector to `img.active`.

Comment: Thank you. Naturally, the project is way more complected than the snippet so thanks for covering all the bases there.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to remove the class using **[`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)** also use **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)** to avoid clicked element otherwise toggling will not work

```js
$(function() {
  var $img = $('img').click(function() {
    $img.not(this).removeClass('active');
    // removing `active` class from images except clicked
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    // toggling class `active` of clicked image
  });
});
```

```css
img.active {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
```

Also you can **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to select its siblings

```js
$(function() {
  var $img = $('img').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
      // toglling active class of clicked image
      .siblings('img')
      // selecting siblings image        
      .removeClass('active');
    // removing class of them
  });
});
```

```css
img.active {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `.siblings()` and the `.end()` to return to the original set up matched elements (i.e. `this`)...

```js
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
       $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').end().toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
img.active {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80">
```